# failureRedirect when using app

Tags: node.js, postgresql, passport.js

I have trouble with authentication. I use passport module and pg for postgres. This code saves data to database successfuly but app go to failureRedirect. Can anybody help me? Thanks

```
passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField : 'username',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
  },
    function(req, username, password, done) {
        pg.connect(db.url, function(err, client) {
            if(err) {
                return done(err);
            } else {
                client.query('INSERT INTO users VALUES($1,$2)',
                    [req.body.nickname,req.body.password],function(err, result) {
                        return done(null, result.rows[0]);
                    });
                }
            });
        }));
app.post('/register',passport.authenticate('local-signup',{
                            failureRedirect : '/register'}),function(req,res){
                                                res.redirect('/login');
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Like adding `console.log(result.rows[0]);` before calling `done()`?